# add something before item quickly in latex

Tags: lists, itemize

i would like to change this long cammend in enumerate envirment at latex

```
\item[\begin{scriptsize} $\lceil 01.00 \rfloor$ن \end{scriptsize} 
    \addtocounter{numebcounte}{1}\thenumebcounte$\langle$]
```

like this

```
\item{01.00}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `\item{0.01}` use `\myitem{0.01}` (or any other command name that you choose) and define it as

```
\newcommand\myitem[1]{%
\item[{\scriptsize $\lceil #1 \rfloor$ن }%
      \addtocounter{numebcounte}{1}\thenumebcounte$\langle$]%
}
```

Comment: I think the number 1.00 is a variable in each item, like the number of points per question.

Comment: @HasanZakeri oops forgot to replace the number by `#1`, fixed, thanks:-)

Comment: thank you very  very very much that's what i want

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution, maybe less elegant using `marginnote` and `enumitem` but including one extra command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[fulladjust]{marginnote}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{numebcounte}
\begin{document}
\reversemarginpar
\lipsum[1]
\newcommand{\points}[1]{\marginnote{\raggedleft\begin{scriptsize}$\lceil #1\rfloor$N \end{scriptsize}}}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*$\langle$]
    \item \points{1.00} Solve number using\dots
    \item \points{2.00} What is the lowest\dots 
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

I can't write Arabic at the moment, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: thank you very much